# How to display same drive letter for different user on same VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, windows-server

I have gone through documentation of azure but didn't find anything to help in below scenario.

I have attached two disks on one VM

1. E: drive(**User 1** private drive)
2. F: drive(**User 2** private drive)

So here are the conditions:

1. User 1 should see only his drive as **D:** drive (currently E: drive)
2. User 2 should see only his drive as **D:** drive (currently F: drive)
3. User 1 & User 2 should not see each other's drive.

We can not use the shared drive for other reasons.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use Targeting via group policy....  you have to set each user in their own group to do it but here's the link to the how-to I used....

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17039-mapping-drives-with-group-policy-preferences-and-item-level-targeting

And the Microsoft Page is here..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc978513(v=technet.10)